# ASP.NET javascript executing on remmed out code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using VS 2019, .net 4.8 and an ASP.NET webforms project I have some javascript in a page where I remmed out 2 lines and added 2 new lines below them.  When I run the project the code still executes on the remmed out lines and skips the new lines.  I even deleted the remmed lines, deleted the bin and obj folders, closed VS, re-opened VS and ran it again, and continue to get the same bad results.  Please see the screenshot.

Any idea what's going wrong here and how to get my revised script to execute?

Thank You!

[image]

Comment: While looking at the web page, try a ctrl-F5 - that should force a re-load of the browser cache - they can be VERY nasty - and often not clear out since the code looks similar to what the browser try to save, hold on to, and do you a favor by not re-loading content.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm!  Great tip to know and will use all the time.  Thank You.

Comment: yes, i spent what - 4 hours on something - a ctrl-F5 fixed it!!! - So browser cache of code can be a HORRIED problem.